# Problem with sentence structure/construction

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

The following are what two authors have written.

1. A further complication was jurisdiction: even if unemployment were admitted as a social, rather than an individual, problem, was insurance against unemployment a federal or a provincial responsibility?
2. There existed some uncertainty regarding constitutional jurisdiction over unemployment assistance. As such, even if unemployment was recognized as a social problem requiring state action, it nevertheless wasn’t completely clear which level of government would be responsible ― federal or provincial.

The one below is my attempt at restructuring the question.

> Another complication, as Smith (1988) pointed out, was constitutional jurisdiction: if unemployment was indeed recognized as a social problem, it was not clear as to which government—federal or provincial—would then be responsible for administering a support program.

The part after the colon, "if unemployment was..." tends to finish the sentence as a question like author 1 (but I don't want that). I am not sure if the way I have written makes sense (ending it as a statement and not a question).

Comment: Your version is a statement, as you say, not a question. It makes good sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

> Which government would have responsibility was not clear.
>
> It was not clear which government would have responsibility.

Comment: Pardon me, I am not sure what you meant. Are you saying that I should cut out **"as to"** and write **"...it was not clear which government—federal or provincial—would then be responsible..."**?

Comment: You can leave **as to** or omit it.  I was trying to give you pared-down examples to make the structure clear to you when using the "cleft" sentence.   **as to**, **in regard to**, **with respect to**, **regarding** could all be used there but they are unnecessary.